# Companion object cannot access private variable on the class

Tags: scala, read-eval-print-loop, companion-object

A rather weird behavior coming from the Scala REPL.

Although the following compiles without a problem:

```
class CompanionObjectTest {
    private val x = 3
}
object CompanionObjectTest {
    def testMethod(y:CompanionObjectTest) = y.x + 3
}
```

the private variable does not seem to be accessible from the companion object in REPL:

```
scala> class CompanionObjectTest {
     | 
     | private val x = 3;
     | }
defined class CompanionObjectTest

scala> object CompanionObjectTest {
     | 
     | def testMethod(y:CompanionObjectTest) = y.x + 3
     | }
<console>:9: error: value x in class CompanionObjectTest cannot be accessed in CompanionObjectTest
       def testMethod(y:CompanionObjectTest) = y.x + 3
                                                 ^
```

Why is that happening?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What is happening is that each "line" on REPL is actually placed in a different package, so the class and the object do not become companions. You can solve this in a few ways:

Make chain class and object definitions:

```
scala> class CompanionObjectTest {
     |   private val x = 3;
     | }; object CompanionObjectTest {
     |   def testMethod(y:CompanionObjectTest) = y.x + 3
     | }
defined class CompanionObjectTest
defined module CompanionObjectTest
```

Use paste mode:

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

class CompanionObjectTest {
    private val x = 3
}
object CompanionObjectTest {
    def testMethod(y:CompanionObjectTest) = y.x + 3
}

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

defined class CompanionObjectTest
defined module CompanionObjectTest
```

Put everything inside an object:

```
scala> object T {
     | class CompanionObjectTest {
     |     private val x = 3
     | }
     | object CompanionObjectTest {
     |     def testMethod(y:CompanionObjectTest) = y.x + 3
     | }
     | }
defined module T

scala> import T._
import T._
```

Answer (score 2):

This is indeed a little weird. To work around this problem, you should enter paste mode first with `:paste`, then define your class and your companion object and exit paste mode with CTRL-D. Here is a sample REPL session:

```
Welcome to Scala version 2.9.0.1 (OpenJDK Server VM, Java 1.6.0_22).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

class A { private val x = 0 }
object A { def foo = (new A).x }

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

defined class A
defined module A

scala>
```